# Token transfer with splToken throwing error wehen asking to sign

Tags: web3.js, spl-token, phantom, javascript

i made a function to transfer a custom token on Solana with spl-token, but when i get to sign the transaction it prompts me this error:

```
Error processing intruction 2: invalid accounr data for instrction
```

Code:

```
transferToken = async () => {
    const tokenAddress = new solanaWeb3.PublicKey("5jFnsfx36DyGk8uVGrbXnVUMTsBkPXGpx6e69BiGFzko");
    const receiver = new solanaWeb3.PublicKey(settings.reciver);

    const blockhash = await this.connection.getRecentBlockhash();

    const from = await splToken.Token.getAssociatedTokenAddress(
        splToken.ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
        splToken.TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
        tokenAddress,
        this.publicKey
    );

    const to = await splToken.Token.getAssociatedTokenAddress(
        splToken.ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
        splToken.TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
        tokenAddress,
        receiver
    );

    let instructions = splToken.Token.createTransferInstruction(
        splToken.TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
        from,
        to,
        this.publicKey,
        [],
        1000000000
    );

    let transaction = new solanaWeb3.Transaction();
    transaction.recentBlockhash = blockhash.blockhash; 

    transaction.add(instructions);

    transaction.feePayer = this.publicKey; 

    const signedTransaction = await this.provider.signTransaction(transaction);
    let signature = await this.connection.sendRawTransaction(signedTransaction);
    await this.connection.confirmTransaction(signature);
    console.log(signature);
}
```

I don't understand why this is not working right..

Answer (score 1):

`getAssociatedTokenAddress` takes as input, in order, the `mint` and then the `owner` to get the token account for. The token program and associated token program IDs are not required if you're using the defaults, but if they are passed they should be the 4th and 5th arguments respectively. See https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-program-library/token/js/functions/getAssociatedTokenAddress.html

So you probably want something like `const from = await splToken.Token.getAssociatedTokenAddress(tokenAddress, this.publicKey);` and `const to = await splToken.Token.getAssociatedTokenAddress(tokenAddress, receiver);

Similarly `createTransferInstruction` also has the wrong arguments. The program ID should not be the first argument, and multisigners comes after amount. Both are optional since you're passing the default values. See https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-program-library/token/js/functions/createTransferInstruction.html

You probably want something like `const instruction = splToken.Token.createTransferInstruction(from, to, this.publicKey, 1000000000)` there.

Comment: hi thanks for the answer, the variable order in my code is set like that because i managed to find an spl js that is similar to the solweb3 which has a global variable from which you call the functions, so when i read the code the "createTransferInstruction" looks like this `Token.createTransferInstruction(this.programId, source, destination, ownerPublicKey, multiSigners, amount)`, i somehow fixed a little biut i have another issue now, is there a way to contact you?

Comment: If you have another question then please open another one on our stackexchange :)